# When fetching data from tables it is showing this error Parameter index out of range(1>number of parameters)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

```
String get_date = check_in_date.getText();
        String get_customer_no = customer_no.getText();
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rst = null;
        try{


String driver ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotel";
        String userid ="root";
        String password ="tushar11";
        Class.forName(driver);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userid,password);
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select occupantdetails.customer_name, 
                hoteldetails.service_detail, hoteldetails.cab_no from 
                occupantdetails JOIN hoteldetails ON 
                occupantdetails.customer_no=hoteldetails.customer_no" );
        pstmt.setString(1, get_customer_no);

        rst = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while(rst.next()){
            txt_customer_name.setText(rst.getString("customer_name"));
            txt_room_no.setText(rst.getString("service_detail"));
            txt_cab_no.setText(rst.getString("cab_no"));
        }

        }
```

I am new to this. As i am fetching the  details it is showing the parameter error and i cannot solve this. I think i have written the right query and there might be mistake in java code.

Comment: Your query doesn't have any parameter. But you still are passing one. So either add the parameter to the query or don't add the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your statement should be something like

```
  "SELECT *
   FROM YourTable  
   WHERE customer_no = ?"
```

Check the tutorial for **[prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)**

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. I am really new to this.